# Transform jquery listener to javascript listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, keylistener

I have such code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var my_id = 'iddate';

      $('#'+ my_id).bind('keyup',function(e){ // Listener for key pressing in the field.
          var inputValue = document.getElementById( my_id ).value;
          // And etc...
      })
  });
</script>
```

Here i used JQuery. But problem is that i can't use it anymore. Is that possible to rewrite it with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, like that for example:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var my_id = 'iddate';

  document.getElementById( my_id ).onkeyup = function(e){ // Listener for key pressing in the field.
      var inputValue = document.getElementById( my_id ).value;
      // And etc...
  };
}
```

Or by using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) :

```
document.getElementById( my_id ).addEventListener('click', function(e){ // Listener for key pressing in the field.
      var inputValue = document.getElementById( my_id ).value;
      // And etc...
}, false);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. My file with code is here - https://gist.github.com/3150612

Comment: As you can see in gist file test alert doesn't work. But why?
I tried that code in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @ExiRe see this http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/26D3Y/ demo (resukt: http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/26D3Y/show/)

Comment: I see that and understand that it works. But in my case everything is very simple and it doesn't run. I just can't get it... (http://jsfiddle.net/QXdKS/1/ - if you are still interesting in).

Comment: Looks like i got it. I just removed empty id and onload from body.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

or you can do it in this way as well,

```
window.onload = function(){
   var my_id = 'iddate';
      document.getElementById( my_id ).onkeyup = function(e){ // Listener for key pressing in the field.
      var inputValue = document.getElementById( my_id ).value;
     };
}
```